# AutoLayout Not Working For 5.5" iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

In my app, I have a screen that needs privacy, so when you first open it, it will check if you have logged in with the password.  If not, it adds another view on top of the SuperView until that password is entered.  I use XIB file for this.  The main View of the screen is a tableview, and I drug on another UIView to use as the Password screen.  However, despite AutoLayout, the Password view is only taking up the dimensions of 4.7" phone, meaning you can see behind it on the edges.  I made sure AutoLayout is enabled, and on the background image, which is the gradient, I added 4 constraints, one for each side, set to 0, so that it would always cover the view behind it, and then set the UILabel to be aligned horizontally in container.  What am I doing wrong?  This works PERFECTLY in a different view and XIB within the same app, and I even copied the view straight over, but it is still messing up on this one class.

Code to load this is (password is the UIView declared in the header as `IBOutlet UIView *password`:

```
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:password];
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the code that loads the xib and adds its contents to the view hierarchy.

Comment: @robmayoff Added that to OP.  Basically just self.navigationcontroller.view addSubview:password

Comment: How should the user log in with this view showing?

Comment: @robmayoff I was in the middle of implementing Touch ID login option when I noticed the issue.  When Touch ID is not present, or at first launch, there is a UITextField that would normally be there.

Comment: Ok, I have figured out the WHY, just not how to fix.  The background image is not stretching any further, because the VIEW itself is only the size of the 6 and 6S, and the background image IS pinned to that.  So, how do I make sure the view stays pinned to the superview, no matter its size?

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to use a view controller to manage the curtain view, and either push that view controller onto the navigation controller's stack, or present it from the navigation controller or the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 possible reason

1. you may not applied constraint on your xib.
2. you have applied constraint on it but when you are initialising your xib you are providing fix frame.

it would better if your share your code how you are doing it ?